# could not extract the Result Set. Table doesn't exist

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot

My App has two Tables in MySQL: Hospital and Doctor, connected @ManyToMany relationship with JoinTable hospital_doctor.

I wrote simple CRUD operations for hospitals and doctors to obtain data but there is a problem...

I want to obtain List of doctors which are in hospital.

So I wrote this simple operation :

My Repo:

```
  @Repository
public interface DoctorDao extends JpaRepository<Doctor, Integer>{

    public List<Doctor> findByHospitalsId(int hospitalsId);

}
```

And Service:

```
public List<Doctor> getDoctorsByHospital(int hospitalsId){
        List<Doctor> doctors = new ArrayList<>();
        doctorDao.findByHospitalsId(hospitalsId).forEach(doctors::add);
        return doctors;
    }
```

And Rest Controller:

```
@GetMapping(value = "api/hospitals/{hospitalsId}/doctors")
public List<Doctor> getDoctorsByHospitalId(@PathVariable int hospitalsId){
    return doctorService.getDoctorsByHospital(hospitalsId);
}
```

I can obtain this data in postman for "/api/hospitals/2" (i insert this data in MySql workbench):

```
[
{
    "name": "Santa barbara",
    "country": "USA",
    "town": "Philadelphia",
    "street": "Saint John",
    "postal_code": "12-124",
    "phone_number": "123-123",
    "fax_number": "1231451",
    "number_of_ambulances": 1,
    "helicopter_access": false,
    "teaching_hospital": false,
    "doctors": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "John",
            "surname": "Doe",
            "title": "doctor",
            "license_number": 2453,
            "phone": "234234",
            "email": "asdf!@sdf.sdf",
            "nationality": "PL",
            "speciality": "asdf",
            "date_of_birth": 1355266800000,
            "is_a_teacher": true
        }
    ],
    "id": 2
}
```

]

**And now I want to make App when I get /api/hospitals/2/doctors it will return the data of all doctors (in this case of one dr John).**

But when I'm sending GET request to /api/hospitals/2/doctors it returns me an 500 server error:

> *could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet",*

and it's a **com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'health.doctor_hospitals' doesn't exist** in my console.

**My models:**

DOCTOR MODEL

```
    @Entity
    public class Doctor {


private Set<Hospital> hospitals;



@Column(name = "Id")
int id;

@Column(name = "name")
String name;

@Column(name = "surname")
String surname;

@Column(name = "title")
String title;

@Column(name = "license_number", unique = true)
int license_number;

@Column(name = "phone")
String phone;

@Column(name = "email")
String email;

@Column(name = "nationality")
String nationality;

@Column(name = "speciality")
String speciality;

@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
@Column(name = "date_of_birth")
Date date_of_birth;

@Column(name = "is_a_teacher")
boolean is_a_teacher;

public Doctor() {

}



public Doctor(Set<Hospital> hospitals, String name, String surname, String 
  title, int license_number, String phone,
        String email, String nationality, String speciality, Date 
    date_of_birth, boolean is_a_teacher) {
    super();
    this.hospitals = hospitals;
    this.name = name;
    this.surname = surname;
    this.title = title;
    this.license_number = license_number;
    this.phone = phone;
    this.email = email;
    this.nationality = nationality;
    this.speciality = speciality;
    this.date_of_birth = date_of_birth;
    this.is_a_teacher = is_a_teacher;
}



@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getSurname() {
    return surname;
}

public void setSurname(String surname) {
    this.surname = surname;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public int getLicense_number() {
    return license_number;
}

public void setLicense_number(int license_number) {
    this.license_number = license_number;
}

public String getPhone() {
    return phone;
}

public void setPhone(String phone) {
    this.phone = phone;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public String getNationality() {
    return nationality;
}

public void setNationality(String nationality) {
    this.nationality = nationality;
}

public String getSpeciality() {
    return speciality;
}

public void setSpeciality(String speciality) {
    this.speciality = speciality;
}

public Date getDate_of_birth() {
    return date_of_birth;
}

public void setDate_of_birth(Date date_of_birth) {
    this.date_of_birth = date_of_birth;
}

public boolean isIs_a_teacher() {
    return is_a_teacher;
}

public void setIs_a_teacher(boolean is_a_teacher) {
    this.is_a_teacher = is_a_teacher;
}

@JsonBackReference
@ManyToMany
public Set<Hospital> getHospitals() {
    return hospitals;
}

public void setHospitals(Set<Hospital> hospitals) {
    this.hospitals = hospitals;
}
}
```

HOSPITAL MODEL
     @Entity

```
 public class Hospital {

@Column(name = "Id")
int Id;
@Column(name = "name", unique = true)
String name;
@Column
String country;
@Column
String town;
@Column
String street;
@Column
String postal_code;
@Column
String phone_number;
@Column
String fax_number;
@Column
int number_of_ambulances;
@Column
boolean helicopter_access;
@Column
boolean teaching_hospital;

public Set<Doctor> doctors;

public Hospital() {

}


public Hospital(String name, String country, String town, String street, 
   String postal_code, String phone_number,
        String fax_number, int number_of_ambulances, boolean 
  helicopter_access, boolean teaching_hospital,
        Set<Doctor> doctors) {
    super();
    this.name = name;
    this.country = country;
    this.town = town;
    this.street = street;
    this.postal_code = postal_code;
    this.phone_number = phone_number;
    this.fax_number = fax_number;
    this.number_of_ambulances = number_of_ambulances;
    this.helicopter_access = helicopter_access;
    this.teaching_hospital = teaching_hospital;
    this.doctors = doctors;
 }


@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
public int getId() {
    return Id;
}
public void setId(int id) {
    Id = id;
}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public String getCountry() {
    return country;
}
public void setCountry(String country) {
    this.country = country;
}
public String getTown() {
    return town;
}
public void setTown(String town) {
    this.town = town;
}
public String getStreet() {
    return street;
}
public void setStreet(String street) {
    this.street = street;
}
public String getPostal_code() {
    return postal_code;
}
public void setPostal_code(String postal_code) {
    this.postal_code = postal_code;
}
public String getPhone_number() {
    return phone_number;
}
public void setPhone_number(String phone_number) {
    this.phone_number = phone_number;
}
public String getFax_number() {
    return fax_number;
}
public void setFax_number(String fax_number) {
    this.fax_number = fax_number;
}
public int getNumber_of_ambulances() {
    return number_of_ambulances;
}
public void setNumber_of_ambulances(int number_of_ambulances) {
    this.number_of_ambulances = number_of_ambulances;
}
public boolean isHelicopter_access() {
    return helicopter_access;
}
public void setHelicopter_access(boolean helicopter_access) {
    this.helicopter_access = helicopter_access;
}
public boolean isTeaching_hospital() {
    return teaching_hospital;
}
public void setTeaching_hospital(boolean teaching_hospital) {
    this.teaching_hospital = teaching_hospital;
}
@JsonManagedReference
@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name = "hospital_doctor", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "hospital_id", referencedColumnName = "Id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "doctor_id", referencedColumnName = "Id"))
public Set<Doctor> getDoctors(){
    return doctors;
}

public void setDoctors(Set<Doctor> doctors) {
    this.doctors = doctors;
}
 }
```

HOSPITAL DOCTOR JOIN

```
 @Entity
    @Table(name="hospital_doctor")
    public class HospitalDoctor implements Serializable{


    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private Doctor doctor;
    private Hospital hospital;
    private Date contract_start_date;
    private Date contract_end_date;
    private String position;
    private String supervisor;
    private boolean part_time;




    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="doctor_id")
    public Doctor getDoctor() {
        return doctor;
    }
    public void setDoctor(Doctor doctor) {
        this.doctor = doctor;
    }
    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="hospital_id")
    public Hospital getHospital() {
        return hospital;
    }
    public void setHospital(Hospital hospital) {
        this.hospital = hospital;
    }
    public Date getContract_start_date() {
        return contract_start_date;
    }
    public void setContract_start_date(Date contract_start_date) {
        this.contract_start_date = contract_start_date;
    }
    public Date getContract_end_date() {
        return contract_end_date;
    }
    public void setContract_end_date(Date contract_end_date) {
        this.contract_end_date = contract_end_date;
    }
    public String getPosition() {
        return position;
    }
    public void setPosition(String position) {
        this.position = position;
    }
    public String getSupervisor() {
        return supervisor;
    }
    public void setSupervisor(String supervisor) {
        this.supervisor = supervisor;
    }
    public boolean isPart_time() {
        return part_time;
    }
    public void setPart_time(boolean part_time) {
        this.part_time = part_time;
     }


     }
```

Comment: "and it's a com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'health.doctor_hospitals' doesn't exist in my console." Did you confirm the database health has the table doctor_hospitals in MySQL?

Comment: Thank You for your answer Raymond. My DB has hospital_doctors joining table. Hospital is managing side of this relation. And my question is: If I have to ve\create another table  or if I can obtain what I want Only with 3 tables? Greetings :)